# Remote desktop to a machine on ipv6 from ipv4 network

Tags: ipv6, remote-desktop, ipv4

**Background**

I have a ipv6 connection at home my prefix is 2a02:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64
I do have a ipv4 address but this seems just to be a shared IP and I have no control over it.

My ISP is Virgin Media Ireland BTW.

My main PC. which has a publicly pingable IPv6 address, and a few VM's running on it as well which are also publicly pingable. Took a while to get the firewall rules setup but got there.

**My Question**
Is there anyway that I can create some sort of tunnel or have some sort of resolution created to allow me to connect to these IP's via IPV4?

I can do that via IPv4 no bother. Set up a dyndns and create forwarding rules to the various machines I want to connect to via different ports.

If I try from a ipv4 machine to RDP into my IPv6 machine with the IPv6 address it obviously won't resolve.

Is there some sort of tunnel that I can create that essentially has a IPv4 endpoint but routes to my IPv6 machines?

Essentially, I'd like to create a dyndns that I can use and then add the port number so my FW directs the traffic internally to various VM's (FTP, VM, IIS)

I hope this makes sense

Comment: Same problem with UPC Austria. Been stuck for 3 years now with a IPv6. Interesting question -> upvoted

Comment: 6to4 and 4to6 are invented for this, nat can do it too

Comment: Do you have a public IPv4 address _anywhere_?

Comment: NAT is for internal networks isn't it? I'm talking about being out on the internet and tunnelling/proxying/remoting in to my ipv6 machines. I know you can use hurricane electric to get to v6 via a tunnel. I was wondering if the reverse was possible. Probably should wait another 5-10 years for ipv6 to be more main stream!

Comment: @JohnKeates 6to4 is not applicable here because Virgin Media didn't give him an IPv4 address. And 4to6 is not applicable as it only supports HTTP (not even HTTPS). Besides the 4to6 draft expired five years ago without ever becoming a standard, and I think that's for the best as it's a terrible design.

Comment: Teredo is my preferred solution for the use case you describe. However since Virgin Media put you behind a shared IPv4 address, you cannot run your own Teredo relay. That means Virgin Media has to run Teredo relays in order for that to work. If you try to use Teredo and Virgin Media don't have relays, the connection will go through public relays that are very unreliable.